# Как связать элементы? Вылетает непонятная ошибка

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

При наведении на любой `"hevr_me"` - КЛАСС `ACTIVE` ПРИСВАИВАЕТСЯ ТОЛЬКО ПЕРВОМУ ЭЛЕМЕНТУ С `ID = "SHARE_000_1"`

Может где-то переменные или в javascripte переписываются или в html data-id... В чём причина?

```
var idHoverMenu = $('.hevr_me').attr('data-ids');
$('.hevr_me').hover(

    function(){
        $('#' + idHoverMenu).addClass('active');
    },

    function(){
        $('#' + idHoverMenu).removeClass('active');
});
```

Есть вот такой скрипт.

```
        <div class="bottom_section">
      <div id="media_btn_phone_close">
        <div class="phon_ru">
          <span>Звонки по России</span>
          <a href="tel:+74951087479">
            +7 495 108 74 79
          </a>
        </div>
        <button class = "close_menu">
          <span></span>
          <span></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <form action="#" id="search_mobile_form">
        <input type="text" class = "modile_search_input" placeholder = "Поиск по названию и ID">
      </form>
      <a data-ids = "drop_000_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Квартиры
        <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
      </a>
      <a data-ids = "drop_001_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Дома
        <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
      </a>
      <a data-ids = "drop_002_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Участки
        <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
      </a>
      <a data-ids = "drop_003_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Бизнес
        <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
      </a>
      <a data-ids = "drop_004_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Коммерция
        <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="hid_wrapper">
        <div id = "drop_000_1" class="drop_menu_second">
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По класу 1
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Кол-во комнат
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По районам
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По статусу
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Дополнительно
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "drop_001_1" class="drop_menu_second">
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По класу2
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Кол-во комнат
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По районам
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По статусу
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Дополнительно
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div id = "drop_002_1" class="drop_menu_second">
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По класу3
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Кол-во комнат
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По районам
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По статусу
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Дополнительно
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "drop_003_1" class="drop_menu_second">
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По класу4
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Кол-во комнат
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По районам
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По статусу
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Дополнительно
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id = "drop_004_1" class="drop_menu_second">
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По класу5
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Кол-во комнат
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По районам
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              По статусу
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col_dst">
            <span class="orange_h">
              Дополнительно
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
            <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Инициализация `idHoverMenu`, должна быть внутри обработчика.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var - вот что пишет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.hevr_me').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
    $('#' + $(this).data('ids')).toggleClass('active', e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

```css
.drop_menu_second.active { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a data-ids = "drop_000_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Квартиры
  <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
</a>
<a data-ids = "drop_001_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Дома
  <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
</a>
<a data-ids = "drop_002_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Участки
  <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
</a>
<a data-ids = "drop_003_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Бизнес
  <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
</a>
<a data-ids = "drop_004_1" href = "#" class="items hevr_me">Коммерция
  <span class="numbers">12 345</span>
</a>
<div id = "drop_000_1" class="drop_menu_second">
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По класу 1
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Кол-во комнат
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По районам
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По статусу
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Дополнительно
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id = "drop_001_1" class="drop_menu_second">
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По класу2
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Кол-во комнат
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По районам
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По статусу
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Дополнительно
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
</div> 
<div id = "drop_002_1" class="drop_menu_second">
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По класу3
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Кол-во комнат
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По районам
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По статусу
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Дополнительно
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id = "drop_003_1" class="drop_menu_second">
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По класу4
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Кол-во комнат
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По районам
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По статусу
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Дополнительно
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id = "drop_004_1" class="drop_menu_second">
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По класу5
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Кол-во комнат
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По районам
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      По статусу
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
  <div class="col_dst">
    <span class="orange_h">
      Дополнительно
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Элитные<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Бизнес-класс<span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
    <a href="#" class="link_sub_menu">Эконом класс <span class="abs_nmb_col">23</span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Топчик, спасибо большое, 15 таймер и принимаю ответ, выручили)))))

Comment: @ДмитрийЗубков, немного изменил js, так более лаконично будет.

Comment: Этто просто нечто))) Огромное спасибо, я пока изучаю только js и мне тяжеловато)

Comment: @ДмитрийЗубков, u are welcome, все там были xDD

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто. Поиск по классу выбирает только первый найденный элемент в DOM. Как в jQ, так и в чистом js. (`document.getElementsByClassName('hevr_me')[0];`). Как вы видите, тут есть `[0]`. То есть: существует массив с элементами одного класса. Мы выбираем по ключу - 0. Если вы хотите, что бы у вас в 1 переменной лежали все элементы с классом `hver_me`, вам нужно использовать цикл `foreach`. С его помощью заполните созданный вами перед циклом массив, допустим, `elements`. Потом С помощью другого цикла `foreach` присвойте всем элементам из вашего массива `elements` класс `active`. По поводу `foreach` - [читать здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/array-iteration).

Comment: Решение, представленное в другом ответе - более рациональное, но я рассказал вам вашу ошибку. Надеюсь - был полезен :) И еще хочу дать совет. Так как вы только недавно начали изучать js - не стоит использовать библиотеки. Лучше все методы, фичи - учить на чистом js. Считайте, тогда вы сможете использовать все фреймворки просто почитав документацию, так как все они (фреймворки) основаны на чистом js.